# R return a conditioned number of objects in a FUNCTION

Tags: r, function, return

I have a function in which I want to return a different object per column of a matrix. However, I don't know how to make the return such that it identifies how many variables  to create within a list given that it will be conditioned to the number of columns of the input matrix.  In other words, how do I change the last command in the following function:

```
f <- function(Treat) {  
for (i in c(1:ncol(Treat))) {
assign(paste0("Treat",i), as.matrix(Treat[,i]))
}
return(dat = list(Treat1=Treat1 , Treat2=Treat2, .....Treatn=Treatn))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lapply` is what you are looking for

```
f <- function(Treat){
    lapply(1:ncol(Treat), function(i) as.matrix(Treat[,i]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lappy works nicely here. But you could also do it with an explicit loop (as per your original example) that assigns to a (pre-initialised) list as it goes:

```
empty_list <- list()                          # inititalise an empty list
f <- function(Treat, empty_list) {            # set up the function
for (i in c(1:ncol(Treat))) {                 # set up the loop
     empty_list[[i]] <- as.matrix(Treat[,i])) # write each column to a new element 
}
return(empty_list)                            # return the list
}
```

You could then use this with:

```
full_list <- f(Treat, empty_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question, suppose I want the function also to return the number of columns into that list. How would I add that object to the empty_list?